# Copy an HTML element on a iframe and print

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I would like to copy a part of my html on iframe to print it. so using VueJs i did this code.

```
  Print:function(){
            var element = document.getElementById('content'); 
            printf.document.body.innerHTML = element;
            window.frames["printf"].focus();
            window.frames["printf"].print();
            },
```

the result is an iframe with : `[object HTMLElement]`.
But When i do a simple test like this one :

```
 Print:function(){
            var element = 'TEST'; 
            printf.document.body.innerHTML = element;
            window.frames["printf"].focus();
            window.frames["printf"].print();
            },
```

A got a printable iframe with TEST

My `content` element is something complicated with full css, tables, pictures etc..  Any orientation ? Thank you !

Comment: `printf.document.body.innerHTML = element` should be `printf.document.body.innerHTML = element.innerHTML` I think. But you may actually want to use outerHTML

Answer (score 1):

`printf.document.body.innerHTML = element` should be `printf.document.body.innerHTML = element.innerHTML`

I think. But you may actually want to use `.outerHTML`